# MongoDB ManytoMany collection aggregate using mongoose, getting values from different collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 3 collections in my mongoDB

1. User(name, address, etc)
2. Task(name, icon, assignee)
3. UserTask(User.ObjectId, Task.ObjectId, date)

User Collection:

```
{
    "users": [
        {
            "name": "Bill",
            "phone": "345"
        },
        {
            "name": "Steve",
            "phone": "123"
        },
        {
            "name": "Elon",
            "phone": "567"
        }
    ]
}
```

Task collection ex:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "name": "Run 100m",
            "icon": "run"
        },
        {
            "name": "Walk 1 hour",
            "icon": "walk"
        },
        {
            "name": "Jog 30 minutes",
            "icon": "jog"
        }
    ]
}
```

UserTasks:

```
{
    "_id": "5e72fec..",
    "user": "5e72fa4..",
    "task": "5e72fbac..",
    "date": "2020-03-03T05:10:10.000Z",
    "createdAt": "2020-03-19T05:10:37.027Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-03-19T05:10:37.027Z",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "5e72fed3..",
    "user": "5e72fa4e..",
    "task": "5e72fbac..",
    "date": "2020-03-12T05:10:10.000Z",
    "createdAt": "2020-03-19T05:10:43.296Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-03-19T05:10:43.296Z",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "5e72fed6..",
    "user": "5e72fa..",
    "task": "5e72fb..",
    "date": "2020-03-15T05:10:10.000Z",
    "createdAt": "2020-03-19T05:10:46.057Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-03-19T05:10:46.057Z",
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "5e72feda...",
    "user": "5e72fa4..",
    "task": "5e72fb..",
    "date": "2020-03-07T05:10:10.000Z",
    "createdAt": "2020-03-19T05:10:50.785Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-03-19T05:10:50.785Z",
    "__v": 0
},
```

user and task contains the objectId in UserTask Collection. I want to get a response from usertasks like below

```
{
    "userTasks": [
      {
        "name": "Walk",
        "icon": "style",
        "assignee": "Steve",
        "log": [
          {
            "name": "Bill",
            "date": "2018-03-15"
          },
          {
            "name": "Elon",
            "date": "2018-02-27"
          },
          {
            "name": "Steve",
            "date": "2018-01-02"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Run",
        "icon": "running",
        "assignee": "Elon",
        "log": [
          {
            "name": "Bill",
            "date": "2019-03-12"
          },
          {
            "name": "Steve",
            "date": "2018-03-03"
          },
          {
            "name": "Elon",
            "date": "2018-03-01"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

How do I achieve this? Is this the best approach in Mongodb? Im used to relational database (SQL etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. ***How to get this result?***

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "tasks",
            localField: "task",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "matchedTask"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$matchedTask"
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "user",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "matchedUser"
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$matchedUser" //can there be tasks with no users? if so we need to tweak this.
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$matchedTask._id",
            name: {$first: "$matchedTask.name"},
            icon: {$first: "$matchedTask.icon"},
            assignee: "???", // what is this field suppose to be?
            log: {
                $push: {
                    name: "$matchedUser.name",
                    date: "$date"
                }
            }

        }
    }
])
```

2. ***Is this the best approach for Mongo?***

Definitely not, Mongo does not like to join data, it is not built to work like a relational database. `$lookup` didn't even exist for the first years of Mongo.

In Mongo data duplication is not a dirty word, it is actually recommended.

If you want a performance boost (and simpler code) i recommend you just merge these 3 collections into one.

** Mind you these are my opinions, I'm sure you'll meet 50 other people saying 50 other things.

Comment: Tasks can have no users, I just noticed you commented on it aswell. How do I solve this issue?

Comment: set `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` to true from the unwind docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Comment: still getting the same results even after I changed the unwind docs
 $unwind: {
        path: "$matchedUser",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
      }

Comment: then there are no tasks without users.

Comment: Thank you so much, Do you know how to sort by date and task._id in desc order? I tried using  {  $sort: { _id: 1, date: -1 }}, the tasks are being sorted but the log.dates is not sorting by date